# XSPEC: What is meaning of Expected Result 'XPath / from:' on test report?

Tags: unit-testing, xslt, xspec

I'm new at XSPEC

I try to run the following test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x:description xmlns:x="http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/xspec" stylesheet="test1.xsl">
    <x:scenario label="Scenario for testing a function">
        <x:context href="test1.xml"/> 
        <x:expect label="expext1" href="result_test1.xml"/>
    </x:scenario>
</x:description>
```

When the content of the relevant files is:

**test1.xsl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="test1">
        <h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </h1>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**test1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test1>text for test</test1>
```

**result_test1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><h1>text for test</h1>
```

The result after run the xspec file is fail,
As shown in the screenshot below:
Next to the expected outcome is the text:
**'XPath / from:'**

***What is meaning of this?***

Below screenshot with the result:

[image: result screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` in this case means a document node.

If you run your test on XSpec v1.3.0 or later, you get more explicit output:

```
Result
XPath /element() from:
```

```
Expected Result
XPath /self::document-node() from:
```

which indicates that you expected a document node but the actual result was an element.

Comment: I run the tests using Oxygen Editor, Saxon Engine 9.8.0.12
1. Where can I check which version of XSPEC I have?
2. What do I actually need to fix so as not to get the above error?

Comment: You can find the version in Oxygen menu - Help - About - Frameworks. Assuming that you expect an element (not a document node), you should add `@select` to `x:expect`: `<x:expect label="expext1" href="result_test1.xml" select="*"/>`

Comment: Thanks. 1. I want to know what select="*" in this context.
2. I checked and saw in my Oxygen Editor (version 21) that it contained xspec in version 1.2.0. How can you upgrade it? 3. How can you tell from the results file (in case of failure), which text was different? Right now I get a file with red and green lilies and can't figure out where the difference is, on the face they look the same. [4. It is also not possible to copy the text from the results file by comparing it with another text comparison tool]

Comment: Used with `@href`, `@select` holds an XPath expression to be evaluated in the context of a document node of `@href`. `*` is an XPath short for `child::*` which selects all child elements of the context node. So `href="result_test1.xml" select="*"` selects `h1` element in `result_test1.xml`. To use external XSpec on oXygen, follow the steps in [XSpec Wiki](https://github.com/xspec/xspec/wiki/Running-with-Oxygen#running-the-latest-version-of-xspec-with-oxygen). Regarding the diff, I'm not sure. You may want to raise another question here or [elsewhere](https://github.com/xspec/xspec#support).